# django rest framework POST error. When I send a JSON/dictionary inside a Json it returns: "Not a valid string."

Tags: json, django, post, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to get this test API working, it is very simple and the model consist of only one class with 2 fields.
My viewset inherits from ModelViewset and I added(to make it more explicit, and make some changes in the future) the list and create function.
I could POST a few JSONs with succes, but when I try to post this one that has a 'nested json' it returns

```
 "Not a valid string."
```

Here is the code and the JSON:

views.py:

```
class SessionViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """"
    A simple viewset for listing or retrieving 'sessions'
    """
    queryset = Session.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Session.objects.all()
        serializer = SessionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

JSON:

```
{
    "meta":"aca va la metadata",
    "reunion":{"juan":500,
            "pedro":300,
            "jose":1000}

}
```

and it returns:

```
{
    "reunion": [
        "Not a valid string."
    ]
}
```

screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the problem]

models:
[models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX8Ew.png)

serializers:
[serializers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLOoh.png)

Do you know if there is any limitation that I'm not aware of, or how can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Tried to POST that JSON, into the API endpoint, with said error response

Comment: maybe try and use json.loads()

Comment: reunion must be a string I guess but you are sending an object. Whats in your model. Can you put it here?

Comment: Could you provide your serializers ?

Comment: updated with models and serializers

Comment: where should I use the json.loads(), and how?

Answer (score 0):

@MS25 as I mentioned in the comment your model has the reunion as `CharField` and you are sending an object data type to it.

If you still want to send the same data to the reunion then try something along the lines:

```
{
    "meta":"aca va la metadata",
    "reunion":JSON.stringify({"juan":500,
            "pedro":300,
            "jose":1000})
}
```

I am not sure of the results maybe it will work maybe not.